# How to create Xpath for regular Expression "data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" in selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver, I have a textbox PND which contains 2 hypens and data enter in the text box is divided according to the hypens in a format of eg 3-2-4. I need Xpath of the Field so that i can provide my Input value.

Html sysntax is below:-

```
<label>                 PND</label>
<input id="PND" class="lname_input valid" type="text" value="" name="Applicant.PND" maxlength="11"         data-val-required="*" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" data-val-regex="Invalid PND format" data-val="true"/>
<span class="validator field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-  for="Applicant.SSN"/>
```

Comment: So you need to find the element using xpath?!  that's what the question really is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XPath for the input field:

```
//input[@id='PND']
```

Although finding the field by id seems simple enough if it is unique. You may have to include the hyphens in the SendKeys string for the validation to work.